# How to Search and print a word in a string based on input command?

Tags: linux

I have a data in file and need to extract particular element based on input command.

Example: Data in file look like:

```
NM1*IL*1*JESSI*PINKMAN*XM*SIRUS~
NM1*IL**WALTER*WHITE*XM*PANDORA*EM*ARIZONA~
```

Input Command:

```
NM1*IL*XM*
```

Expected Output:

```
SIRUS
PANDORA
```

Input Command:

```
NM1*IL*EM*
```

Expected Output:

```
ARIZONA
```

I have code which extract the segment.

grep -P -o '(?<=NM1[* ]IL).*?(?=~)'

this code gives the data between NM1*IL and ~

```
*1*JESSI*PINKMAN*XM*SIRUS
**WALTER*WHITE*XM*PANDORA*EM*ARIZONA
```

Now i have to search again for string XM in this output and get data next to XM* 
so i appended code as below

```
grep -P -o '(?<=NM1[*]IL).*?(?=~)' | grep -P -o '(?<=XM[*]).*?(?=[*]ORNULL)'
```

Not sure how i can give end string to be as * or ENDOFLINE

Comment: It looks like your input is `*` separated columns, or perhaps `*` or `~` separated.  It really suggests something like `awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if( match($i,m)) print $(i+1) }' FS='\\*|~' m=XM input`

Comment: Although probably cleaner to write `awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if( match($i,m)) print $(i+1) }' FS='[*~]' m=XM input`

Comment: thanks William.  In file there can be multiple segments which contains XM.  But in reality i want to print only from NM1 segment. thats is why i first extracted NM1 segment then look for XM element inside that.   That is why i used below code grep -P -o '(?<=NM1[*]IL).*?(?=~)' | grep -P -o '(?<=XM[*]).*?(?=[*]ORNULL)'     but not sure what to use for ?=[*]ORNULL

Comment: first grep command gives the output as given above (extracts data between NM1 and ~)


from this output i am trying to get data between XM* and before next element

grep -P -o '(?<=XM[ * ]).*?(?=[ * ]|~|\n\r)'

but \n\r not working as EOL.   Because after SIRIUS there is no element to identify and therefore i am giving EOL character \n\r

Comment: I am using sed command to solve this  grep -P -o '(?<=NM1[ * ]IL).*?(?=~)' FILE.txt | sed -ne 's/$/EOLINE&/p'|grep -P -o '(?<=XM[ * ]).*?(?=[ * ]|~|EOLINE)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using sed command to solve this

grep -P -o '(?<=NM1[* ]IL).*?(?=~)' FILE.txt | sed -ne 's/$/EOLINE&/p' | grep -P -o '(?<=XM[ * ]).*?(?=[ * ]|~|EOLINE)'

Explanation command by command

grep -P -o '(?<=NM1[* ]IL).*?(?=~)' FILE.txt

extracts data between NM1* IL and ~

sed -ne 's/$/EOLINE&/p'

sed suffix EOLINE for the output of grep

grep -P -o '(?<=XM[* ]).*?(?=[ * ]|~|EOLINE)'

again taking the data between XM* and (* or ~ or EOLINE)